# Google maps API geocode - additional parameter

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have

```
var marker  = geo.geocode({address: adr}, geoc);
```

where

```
function geoc(results, status) {...
```

I want to set additional parameter to the function **geoc** but I do not know how to call **geoc** with three parameters.
How to do it, please help, I'am noob in JS :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use anonymously function for that:

```
var marker  = geo.geocode({address: adr}, function(results, status) {
    geoc(results, status, thirdParam);
});
```

And in your `geoc` function:

```
function geoc(results, status, someParam) {...
```

Comment: uuu, sorry, My mistake. Works fine! Thank you.